# Add ajax function to multiple elements

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter and seem to be a little stuck with a feature. I have a list of titles on the home page:

```
<?php foreach($sqlquery->result() as $item): ?>

     <h1><?php echo $item->name; ?></h1>
<button onlick="loadXMLDoc()">Change</button>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<div id="myDiv">This content will change when button is pressed!</div>
```

I want to load the content in the myDiv div from http://mysite.com/index.php/home/show/9/comm. The view show will display data depending on what id (9) and what category (comm) is in the url:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }

xmlhttp.open("GET","http://mysite.com/index.php/home/show/9/comm ", true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
<button onlick="loadXMLDoc()">Change</button>
```

I tried adding the function in the foreach and changed the GET url but couldn't get it to work:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://mysite.com/index.php/home/show/<? echo $item->id; ?>/<? echo $item->cat; ?> ", true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've hard-coded the item ID into the loadXML doc function, so no matter WHERE you call it from, it'll always fetch the same data. You need to pass in the item id associated with the button that was clicked, at bare minimum:

```
function loadXMLDoc(id) {
                    ^^--add this
   blah blah blah
   xmlhttp.open("GET","http://mysite.com/index.php/home/show/' + id + '/comm ", true);
                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^--- add this
   blah blah blah
}
```

and

```
<?php foreach($sqlquery->result() as $item): ?>
     <h1><?php echo $item->name; ?></h1>
<button onlick="loadXMLDoc(<?php echo $item->id ?>)">Change</button>
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---add this
```

Beyond that, consider switching to jquery. it's far easy to do ajax stuff with jquery (your entire loadxmldoc function can be reduced to a **SINGLE** line with jquery). And you can also eliminate the need to embed item ids into the function call and use some simple dom lookups to fetch the associated id directly from the webpage's dom.